# Ambari agent installation on ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit

Is it possible to install Ambari agent/server (any version) on 32Bit Ubuntu 14.04? Tryed to install it using the instructions on ambari.apache.org but the ambari-agent or ambari-server is not show up in the apt with the 2.2.0 version. Is there another way to install it or is there any earlier version supporting 32 bit?

Comment: Better :-) time to delete the comments (like i did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambari agent not available for Ubuntu or 32 bit Platform :

**2.2. Operating Systems Requirements**

The following operating systems are supported:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) v5.x or 6.x (64-bit)
- CentOS v5.x or 6.x (64-bit)
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 11, SP1 (64-bit)

https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.0/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap1-2.html

Comment: It says also ubuntu for latest version, and also mentions just 64bit. I was wondering if one of the earliest versions are support 32bit.

Comment: @nagellette Under where does it state this?  According to [here](http://ambari.apache.org/install.html) which is the Install page for Ambari, only RHEL based distros are supported, as Ramesh shows here.  Where did you hear it would be supported on Ubuntu?  (Because it isn't)

Comment: @Ramesh Chand, please check ambari.apache.org. see "Getting Started with Ambari"

Comment: Please read the same end of the same page http://ambari.apache.org/ .

**Note: Ambari currently supports the 64-bit version of the following Operating Systems:**

RHEL (Redhat Enterprise Linux) 5 and 6
CentOS 5 and 6
OEL (Oracle Enterprise Linux) 5 and 6
SLES (SuSE Linux Enterprise Server) 11
Ubuntu 12 and 14
Debian 7

Comment: .... I was wondering if one of the earliest versions are support 32bit.